# Alinhamento de elementos por linha

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando alinhar os elementos, mas sem sucesso.
A idéia é limitar por linha apenas 8 elementos, além de não acontecer isso, ainda fica retornando erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Elementos desalinhados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Códigos:

Html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                <h3 class="box-title">
                    Eventos por Operador
                </h3>

            </div>
            <div class="box-body" id="bolhas">
             <!-- Carregar os elementos do JavaScript aqui -->
                </div>
            <div class="overlay">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
            </div>



        </div>

    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function PreencherBolhas(){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Developer/GetContadoresOperadoresEventos',
        success: function (data) {
            var linha = "<div class='col-lg-6' style='padding-right:0px;'>";
            var row = "<div class='col-lg-6' style='padding-right:0px;'>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var temp = data[i];
                linha += "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
                linha += "<div class='small-box bg-yellow'>";
                linha += "<div class='inner'>";
                linha += "</div>";
                linha += "</div>";
                linha += "<h2 style='margin-left: 2.5vw;'>" + temp.percentual + " %" +  "</h2>";
                linha += "<p style='color: black'>" + temp.dsNome + "</p>";
                linha += "</div>";
            }
            linha += "</div>";
            var html = document.getElementById('bolhas');
            var box = document.getElementsByClassName('col-lg-12');
            html.innerHTML = linha;
            document.box.appendChild(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Enfim não sei como corrigir, se alguém puder me orientar.

Comment: Igor não fica 8 por linha que vc está colocando `col-lg-3`, dessa forma vão ficar 4 por linha mesmo, pois 3+3+3+3 = 12 que é o limite de colunas do Grid do Bootstrap! Inclusive vc só consegue dividir as colunas em múltiplos de 12 logo 8 por coluna não é possível, pois 8/12 vc precisaria de uma `col-lg-1,5` o que não existe... Acho que vc vai ter que organizar seus itens de outra forma

Comment: O erro vc conserta alterando a linha para `box[0].appendChild(html);`.